# Position a div dynamically below another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to use jQuery to detect the position of a div (.field_slide-produit), so I can use that position to place another div (.slider-content) exactly below it on the bottom left and i need to replace this div dynamically on window resize.

I've used this code, but it's not working, an idea why ?

```
var offset = $('.field_slide-produit').offset();
var height = $('.field_slide-produit').height();
var width = $('.field_slide-produit').width();
var top = offset.top + height + "px";
var right = offset.left + width + "px";

$('.slider-content').css( {
'position': 'absolute',
'right': right,
'top': top
});

// listen the window changes and correct the newdiv position
$(window).resize(function(){ slider-content(); });
```

This code is in a codepen here : http://codepen.io/Laurentfrom47/pen/wJEKVb

Thanks

Comment: You call a function `slider-content();` but there is no function called that. Put the code inside that function for it to work.

Comment: Also in your pen you do not include jquery so it will not work.

Comment: is this the desired result? [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpGedg)

Comment: No SerCrAsH i need the red box on the blue box in bottom left

Comment: In fact need this http://i.imgur.com/EJBkond.jpg

Comment: Updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpGedg) @Laurent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do your job by only css also

You can add moveit class and its absolute so resize will work fine

```
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.field_slide-produit {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.slider-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.main_container{
    position: relative;
}
.moveit{
      position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="field_slide-produit">
  </div>
  <div class="slider-content moveit">
  </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you included  jquery file there ?

Also on window resizing ,  slider-content() function is calling but thats not defined

```
function slider-content(){
$('.slider-content').css( {
'position': 'absolute',
'right': right,
'top': top
});
}
```

Check these points and you will get your expected result

Comment: Sorry can you modify the codepen for me http://codepen.io/Laurentfrom47/pen/wJEKVb

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .field_slide-produit {
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .slider-content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="field_slide-produit"></div>
  <div class="slider-content">
  </div>
  <script>
  var offset = $('.field_slide-produit').offset();
  var height = $('.field_slide-produit').height();
  var width = $('.field_slide-produit').width();

  var slider_height = $('.slider-content').height();
  var slider_width = $('.slider-content').width();

  var new_top = Number(height - (offset.top + slider_height) ) + "px";
  var new_left = (offset.left + offset.left) + "px";
  function slidercontent() {
    $('.slider-content').css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'left': new_left,
      'top': new_top
    });
  }
  slidercontent();
  // listen the window changes and correct the slider-content div position
  $(window).resize(function() {
    slidercontent();
  });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```